# MediaWiki TemplateParser.php internal error

Tags: mediawiki, internals

I have a local wiki (MediaWiki 1.38.4 ; Apache with xampp) that worked perfectly for a few weeks, but today started giving me errors with the TemplateParser.php and now is completely unnaccesible and shows the following error details:

```
MediaWiki internal error.

Original exception: [3d60e113338e8a53946d26be] /fangirlbook/index.php/P%C3%A1gina_principal TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string
Backtrace:
from C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\TemplateParser.php(134)
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\TemplateParser.php(289): TemplateParser->getTemplate(string)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\skins\SkinMustache.php(65): TemplateParser->processTemplate(string, array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\skins\Vector\includes\SkinVector.php(455): SkinMustache->generateHTML()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\skins\SkinTemplate.php(150): Vector\SkinVector->generateHTML()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\OutputPage.php(2807): SkinTemplate->outputPage()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\MediaWiki.php(926): OutputPage->output(boolean)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\MediaWiki.php(939): MediaWiki::{closure}()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\MediaWiki.php(563): MediaWiki->main()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#10 {main}

Exception caught inside exception handler: [3d60e113338e8a53946d26be] /fangirlbook/index.php/P%C3%A1gina_principal TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string
Backtrace:
from C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\TemplateParser.php(134)
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\TemplateParser.php(289): TemplateParser->getTemplate(string)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\skins\SkinMustache.php(65): TemplateParser->processTemplate(string, array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\skins\Vector\includes\SkinVector.php(455): SkinMustache->generateHTML()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\skins\SkinTemplate.php(150): Vector\SkinVector->generateHTML()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\OutputPage.php(2807): SkinTemplate->outputPage()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\exception\MWExceptionRenderer.php(157): OutputPage->output()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\exception\MWExceptionRenderer.php(76): MWExceptionRenderer::reportHTML(TypeError)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\exception\MWExceptionHandler.php(107): MWExceptionRenderer::output(TypeError, integer)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\exception\MWExceptionHandler.php(202): MWExceptionHandler::report(TypeError)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\includes\MediaWiki.php(585): MWExceptionHandler::handleException(TypeError, string)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\fangirlbook\index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#12 {main}
```

I have already restarted the system, re-installed the wiki and copying the manual backup I had of the files and the database, and no solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the skin Vector has the same major version as MediaWiki. You may also need to run `composer update`.

Comment: I don't know how, but I managed to turn back in time the xampp folder and now I can see the wiki, but I couldn't edit anything since there was a log in problem. I'm still unable to resolve this new issue